# How to use shell variables with GNU parallel?

Tags: shell, variables, gnu-parallel

This is the content of `list.csv`:

```
Apple,Red,10
Banana,Yellow,3
Coconut,White,18
```

Suppose I have this `GNU parallel` command:

```
parallel -a list.csv -j0 -C, \
color=`echo {2} | sed 's/e/eee/g' | ./capitalize.sh` ";" \
echo "{2}" ";" \
echo "$color" ";"
```

To get:

```
Red
REEED
Yellow
YEEELLOW
White
WHITEEE
```

Why isn't the `color` variable being defined/printed?

**EDIT 20151218:**
Now that I got the quoting right, I'd like to introduce a function reading a variable from another function, and reading `$0`.

This is a working example without `GNU parallel` (I made `grep` case-insensitive before posting, to facilitate testing without `./capitalize.sh`).

```
while read line; do
doit() {
   color=`echo $1 | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/e/eee/g' | ./capitalize.sh`
}
export -f doit

get_key() {
   key=`grep -i $color $0 | cut -d, -f2`
}
export -f get_key
                   #note that I would use parallel's `-C,` here instead of `cut`.
  doit $line       #get CSV's 2nd element and make it look like the one in script.
  get_key          #extract this element's value from the script's comments.
  echo "color: $color"
  echo "key: $key"
done < list.csv

#Key database in the shell script
# REEED,r-key
# YEEELLOW,y-key
# WHITEEE,w-key
```

Working output:

```
color: REEED
key: r-key
color: YEEELLOW
key: y-key
color: WHITEEE
key: w-key
```

Comment: This is so wrong I'm not sure that starting with the existing code is reasonable. You might consider backing up and describing what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: (and why parallel is being a part of that goal -- in general, if you want output in a well-defined order, parallel is not typically an appropriate tool for the job, since there's no guarantee that one task it spawns won't start printing in the middle of the output of another one; to avoid that would need the use of `-k` / `--keep-order` to buffer and reassemble output).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you're only using parallel because its support for CSV input, there are far, **far** better ways to do that in shell without it. (And everything else -- you can do the string manipulations and capitalization using only shell builtins much, much more efficiently than starting external tools like `sed`).

Comment: This is obviously a simplified version, and it does work (except for the variable). Yes, it is overkill _in this case_, but that is beside the point. Its sole purpose is to illustration this question's title.

Comment: As for why the code in your question doesn't work -- the command substitution expression is executed by the shell that starts parallel **before parallel is ever run**.

Comment: ...personally, even if you wanted to do something like this in parallel (meaning that in the generic "multiple threads of execution concurrently" sense), I'd use an `xargs -P bash -c '...' _` approach -- much simpler and more explicit than GNU parallel in terms of what it's doing under the hood, and thus much easier to prove correct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy May I challenge you to write this: parallel -a list.csv -j0 -C, echo {3}";" echo '{=2 s/e/eee/g; s/\b(\w)/uc($1)/ge =}' using xargs -P ... ?

Comment: @OleTange, gladly -- though of course I'll have more of the work done by the shell (albeit using builtins efficiently) rather than parallel itself. Can we assume bash 4.0 or newer locally available?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, but you will need to make sure there is no mixing of outputs from different jobs (i.e. if you run 100 jobs in parallel 'echo {3}' must be followed by the second echo and not by 'echo {3}' from another job).

Comment: Hmm. Under other circumstances that might be a moderately tricky guarantee to make without significant performance impact, but here, our writes are small enough to guarantee that they can be performed atomically by a single syscall.

Comment: Thus: `xargs -P "$(nproc)" bash -c 'for line; do IFS=, read -a words <<<"$line"; printf -v output "%s\n" "${words[1]^}" "${words[1]^^}"; printf '%s' "$output"; done`

Comment: ...if I couldn't get away with that assumption, I'd be writing each process's output to a distinct file on tmpfs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your code does not do the same and it mixes output if values in the second columns are 60k chars long.

Comment: @OleTange, sure -- I was clear about the assumption I was making in my comment above, and about the workaround I'd take if that assumption were wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98285/discussion-between-ole-tange-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a single function to do everything.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Key database in the shell script
# REEED,r-key
# YEEELLOW,y-key
# WHITEEE,w-key

doit() {
  # get CSV's 2nd element and make it look like the one in script.
  color=`echo $3 | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/e/eee/g' | ./capitalize.sh`
  #extract this element's value from the script's comments.
  key=`grep -i $color $1 | cut -d, -f2`
  echo "color: $color"
  echo "key: $key"
}
export -f doit

#note that I would use parallel's `-C,` here instead of `cut`.
parallel -C, doit $0 < list.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
parallel -a list.csv -j0 -C, 'color=`echo {2} | sed "s/e/eee/g" | ./capitalize.sh`' ";" echo "{2}" ";" echo '"$color"' ";"
```

You are being hit by inadequate quoting. It might be easier to use a function:

```
doit() {
   color=`echo $2 | sed 's/e/eee/g' | ./capitalize.sh`
   echo "$2"
   echo "$color"
}
export -f doit
parallel -a list.csv -j0 -C, doit
```

If this is the real goal you might want to use {= =} instead which is made for similar situations:

```
parallel -a list.csv -j0 -C, echo {2}";" echo '{=2 s/e/eee/g; $_=uc($_) =}'
```

If you are using $color several times, then --rpl can introduce a shorthand:

```
parallel --rpl '{clr} s/e/eee/g; $_=uc($_)' -a list.csv -j0 -C, echo {2}";" echo '{2clr} and again: {2clr}'
```

From the xargs afficionados I would really like to see a solution using xargs that:

- guarantees not mixing output from different jobs - even if the lines are 60k long (e.g. the value of $color is 60k long)
- sends stdout to stdout, and stderr to stderr
- does not skip jobs even if the list of jobs (list.csv) is bigger than the number of available processes in the process table - even if `capitalize.sh` takes a full minute to run (xargs -P0)

Comment: Your first suggestion works perfectly. I had less luck with the function, because I don't want it to print the result right away: it will be printed and referenced later in the code. As we are going deeper down the rabbit hole, I now have a problem reading this variable from within another variable. See the updated question.

Comment: @octosquidopus It is easier to see the solution if you show us the working code before putting it into GNU Parallel.

Comment: I updated my question with an example, and I'm rewriting my `GNU parallel` command to use functions, because my nested quotes are now close to being unmanageable).